# Insert Into Values?

Tags: sql, insert-into

So I was ask to create a table, then insert into w/ values.  I'm not looking for someone to do it for me just need some help with it.

All the book said was to, Insert values into the table with the INSERT INTO .. VALUES option.  Use the form of INSERT INTO.. VALUES that requires you to have a value for each column; therefore, if if you have a customer number, address, balance, you must insert three values with INSERT INTO .. VALUES.

```
CREATE TABLE Cust (Customer_Number CHAR(3),
Adress CARCHAR(20),
Balance SMALLMONEY)
```

I have that for my table, then

```
INSERT INTO Cust (Customer_Number, Balance, Address)
VALUES ('101', '200'
'102', '700'
'103', '1000'
'104', '1500'
'105', '2000')
```

Not sure if any of what I asked or what I have down is right, but any help will help me alot, thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 4):

So, the specified *columns* (in your case `Customer_Number`, `Balance` and `Address`) need to match up with the array of values (101, 200, 102, etc).  In your case, they don't.  You want something more like:

```
INSERT INTO Cust (Customer_Number, Balance, Address)
VALUES (101, 50.00, '123 Main Street');
```

This will create a *single row* with a `Customer_Number` of 101, a `Balance` of 50.00, and an `Address` of *123 Main Street*.  If you want to insert *multiple rows*, you'll need to specify *multiple* sets of rows in your `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Cust (Customer_Number, Balance, Address)
VALUES (101, 50.00, '123 Main Street'), (102, 75.00, '123 Pine Ave');
```

Comment: Whether or not multiple `insert` statements are required depends on the DBMS. Most DBMS allow the `values` row constructor to create more than one row.

Comment: Yea, I think some databases allow something like `VALUES ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))` but this isn't standard.  I wanted to keep my answer standards compliant as no specific RDMS was mentioned.

Comment: Using a row constructor (`values ( (1,2), (2,3), ...)` *is* defined in the SQL standard. `<insert columns and source>` can be a `<from constructor>` and that can be a `<contextually typed table value constructor>` which is the `values` clause creating multiple rows (it's defined as `Feature F641, "Row and table constructors"`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Ah, was never sure if that was standard syntax.  I've updated my answer.